# CSS background won`t showup

Tags: css

Yo guys, I spent hour of searching for a problem but I havent found any solution, it is easiest problem but to be honest I forget how this one is working, I am searching for an hour now but I haven`t found solution, background just wont show up. Is there any solution?

```
body {
    background: url('/img/back1.jpg');
}
```

Comment: Need more information. How does your HTML file look like?

Comment: Why would you have needed the HTML for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its your location of the page. If css is in separate folder and as shown above img folder is there so path will be:
`body {
    background: url('../img/back1.jpg');
}`

or if css is on the root try this:
`body {
    background: url('./img/back1.jpg');
}`